# RDBM - one to one -> check if entry exists and insert/update OR always delete and only insert?

Tags: database, performance, sql-update, sql-insert, one-to-one

Unfortunately I have no better idea how to name this question, so if you have better suggestion go ahead and edit it :-)

Since years I have been using this approach when trying to insert/update a one-to-one resource: perform a `DELETE` to make sure there is no row with such PK and then perform `INSERT` only. I always thought this is the best case both for performance and simplicity. When talking about performance I mean on both sides - DB and application layer (i.e. executing a `DELETE` query seems to be less expensive than executing a `SELECT` and checking on the result, also when considering there are data being transferred both directions).

But of course there are other approaches, like `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, `IF EXISTS (SELECT ...) UPDATE ... ELSE INSERT...` or `UPDATE ... ;IF ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT ...` (depending on the underlying RDBMS) and of course performing the same on the application layer, i.e. first check whether the entry exists and if it does perform an `UPDATE`, `INSERT` otherwise (or perform `UPDATE` and check number of affected rows, if zero, perform an `INSERT` [which brings another complication since if `UPDATE` does not change the underlying resource, it also returns zero as number of affected rows thus following `INSERT` will return a *duplicate PK error*])...

I am now curious what is the best approach? By best I mean if you consider performance, best practice, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is the only sane thing to do; it's simpler and its intention is clear - it's easy to read. It will also perform much better too, since the index entry doesn't need to be changed.

Using `DELETE` then `INSERT` is vulnerable to a race condition if two processes try to simultaneously update the same key, which would result in a unique key violation for one of the processes. It's also much slower, because not only must a row be physically deleted and a new one inserted, the index entry must also be deleted then inserted too.

Using `IF EXISTS` is not a good choice either, because you must do it from within a stored procedure, so it's locked to that invocation choice and can't be ported into an application. Plus, it's just an attempt at replicating the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` built-in command, so it will never be as efficient.

---

Responding to comment regarding *programmer* performance, ie efficiency, which IMHO is very important too.

If you want to avoid duplicating parameters, add a little refactoring for convenience:

```
void applyTwice(PreparedStatement stmt, int fromIndex, Object... values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        stmt.setObject(i + fromIndex, values[i]);
        stmt.setObject(i + fromIndex + values.length, values[i]);
    }
}
```

Calling this like:

```
applyTwice(stmt, 3, "foo", "bar", 99);
```

Will effectively do this:

```
stmt.setObject(3, "foo");
stmt.setObject(4, "bar");
stmt.setObject(5, 99);
stmt.setObject(6, "foo");
stmt.setObject(7, "bar");
stmt.setObject(8, 99);
```

The `fromIndex` parameter allows for non-repeated parameters like ids etc that aren't repeated in the query.

You could also make a simple method that applies a single value at multiple indexes:

```
void apply(PreparedStatement stmt, Object value, int... indexes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        stmt.setObject(indexes[i], value);
    }
}
```

Which you would call like:

```
apply(stmt, "foo", 3, 6);
```

Comment: OK, seems reasonable to me, especially when talking about performance. It has one backdrop though - in case I am *preparing* a statement and then *executing* it while providing all the variables as parameters, using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` I'll have to duplicate them, resulting in e.g. 20 parameters instead of 10... But I am aiming for performance, so typing little bit more for it is worthy :-)

Comment: @shadyyx I've added some possible relief to your doubling up of typing

Comment: OK, thanks for the code sample, but I'd have to come with completely different solution, as named parameters in my case (GoLang) are not set separately (i.e. `stmt.setParam()` but by passing to `exec()`, i.e. `stmt.Exec(param1, param2, param3, ..., paramX)`). But it is possible to just make *an array* (in Go it's `slice`) of dupplicated  values and then just pass them this way `stmt.Exec(params...)` (literally with this three dots). Nevertheless, how does `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` comply with **REST PUT** - i.e. a resource is *replaced* entirely with PUT request?

Comment: @shady it complies with PUT. The DB entity (the row) is *effectively* replaced. Technically, the physical row is potentially being reused, but that's an implementation detail. The result passes all tests for PUT.